# Drop down values sending '0' instead of value to message box in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, messagebox

I am using VB 2013 and trying to send values from a dropdown to a message box, but it's returning 0. My code is as below :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim value1 As String
        Dim value2 As String

        value1 = Val(Project_Name.SelectedItem)
        value2 = Val(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(value1, value2)

    End Sub
```

[image]

Where have I gone wrong? Appreciate any help / suggestion. I am completely new to Vb.net

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict. `value1 = Val(Project_Name.SelectedItem)` is converting object to double in order to assign to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Format` like :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim value1 As String
            Dim value2 As String
            value1 = Project_Name.SelectedItem.ToString()
            value2 = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
          Dim s As String = String.Format("Value 1: {0}  value2 : {1}", value1 , value2)
            Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s)

        End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .SelectedItem you should used .SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

First up the Val function 'Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type'. Your entry 'Card Center Team' doesn't have any numbers so Val will return 0.

If you are actually looking to get the option selected by the user i.e. 'Card Center Team' then you should use:

```
Dim value1 As String
value1 = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use SelectedItem.ToString().

```
value1 = Project_Name.SelectedItem.ToString()
value2 = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Val()` convert all value to numeric. so if you passing numeric value not problem suppose you passing char,string,hexa value it convert to numeric. that is problem to you facing.

[Val Example1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx)

[Val Example2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0(v=vs.110).aspx)